# How to open a file for reading and writing, writing over the previous content? (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a file that contains a single number. I want to open it so that I can read that number, perform some other statements, and then overwrite that number with a new one, finally closing the file.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
$file = fopen("last.txt","r+");
$firstNumber = fgets($file);
rewind($file);
...
fwrite($file,$secondNumber);
fclose($file);
```

However the code above is simply appending the second number after the previous one.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: Works OK for me. Check if you have correct data in `$secondNumber` while writing and check if your resource is seekable.

Comment: On my local machine it works fine too, but for some reason on my server it does not...

Comment: Check with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php if the resource is seekable. May be some issues with modules/file system limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , the simplest way

```
$firstNumber=file_get_contents("last.txt");
file_put_contents("last.txt",$secondNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not reading the file, then dropping it and creating a new file with the same filename as the one just dropped?

Comment: That's an option I hadn't considered, so thanks. Still, there must be a way to overwrite without having to close it?

Comment: @dom Because it is too much for this simple action.

Answer (score 0):

Loading data

```
$data = file_get_contents($file);
```

Manipulating data:

```
$data = 'newsomething';
```

Saving the data

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);

//Or like Akhil Thayyil said
file_put_contents($file,$data);
```